# C# Canvas Scrollbar isn't working / isn't "active"

Tags: c#, canvas, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I got a problem with the ScrollViewer in Visual Studio.
First off, I'm german and my english isn't that good, so I hope you guys understand me.
Here's the problem:

I made a timetable in C# and it's way too big for the window to display everything on the timetable. Then I added scrollbars but the problem is that they're not "active". Means I can't scroll even though they're visible. I have no idea what isn't working there, so I thought you could help me. Hopefully somebody knows how to solve the problem.
Here's the code for the scrollviewer:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
       <Canvas x:Name="uiCVStundenplan"  Background="White" Margin="116,65,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

       </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As I said before, the timetable is way too big for the window. So I don't understand why the scrollbars aren't active.

I hope I explained it well enough for you. I'm counting on you!♥

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake in your code. You forget a double quote after HorizontalScrollBarVisibility, after Visible.

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
       <Canvas x:Name="uiCVStundenplan"  Background="White" Margin="116,65,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

       </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```